# SonarCube Analyse docker-image

Tags: c#, docker, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure Pipeline that compiles my Web-Project by using a docker-file (actually docker-compose). Now I want to check for code-smells and evaluate my test-results using SonarQube. So I added SonarCube to my pipeline:

```
steps:
- task: SonarQubePrepare@5
  inputs:
    SonarQube: 'MySonarCubeServiceConnection'
    scannerMode: 'MSBuild'
    projectKey: 'MySonarCubeProject'
    extraProperties: |
      sonar.host.url=https://mysonarcubeinstance.com
      sonar.sources="myProject"

- task: DockerCompose@0
  displayName: "Build the images"
  inputs:
    dockerComposeFile: '**/docker-compose.yml'

- task: SonarQubeAnalyze@5
- task: SonarQubePublish@5
  inputs:
    pollingTimeoutSec: '300'
```

However when I run this, I get this error

> The SonarScanner for MSBuild integration failed: SonarQube was unable
> to collect the required information about your projects. Possible
> causes:
>
> 1. The project has not been built - the project must be built in between the begin and end steps
> 2. An unsupported version of MSBuild has been used to build the project. Currently MSBuild 14.0.25420.1 and higher are supported.
> 3. The begin, build and end steps have not all been launched from the same folder
> 4. None of the analyzed projects have a valid ProjectGuid and you have not used a solution (.sln)

My dockerfile is this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["MyProject/MyProject.csproj", "MyProject/"]
RUN dotnet build "MyProject/MyProject.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/build
RUN dotnet build "MyProjectTests/MyProjectTests.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/build
RUN dotnet test /app/build/MyProject.dll

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyProject/MyProject.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/publish --no-restore

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll", "--environment=Development"]
```

How can I scan a project that is built within a container?

EDIT: When I perform the analysis directly in the container (not in the pipeline), everything works fine:

```
# Install sonarscanner and its dependencies
...
RUN dotnet sonarscanner begin /k:"MySonarCubeProject" /d:sonar.login=MySonarCubeAccessToken /d:sonar.host.url=https://mysonarcubeinstance.com
RUN dotnet build "MyProject/MyProject.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/build
RUN dotnet build "MyProjectTests/MyProjectTests.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/build
RUN dotnet test /app/build/MyProjectTests.dll
RUN dotnet sonarscanner end /d:sonar.login=MySonarCubeAccessToken
```

But this way whenever someone locally compiles the project, the analysis is deployed to `mysonarcubeinstance`, which I want to avoid. Only on commit analysis should be published.